# Retrieving target folder from Testdroid server side execution

Tags: android, jenkins, automation, testdroid, bitbar

I'm trying to create a server-side **testdroid** execution for my android automation test using Jenkins. But, it's kinda hard to get the whole "target" folder send back to my Jenkins. Has anyone have any idea how to do that?

They have some API to get the test result info, but no one mentioned about retrieving "target" folder.

Comment: First of all, your requirement is more like for a build service. This functionality is possible with Testdroid, but not by default. You should contact support in order to proceed.